# After joining data from csv file to shapefile, why are all values zero in categorized renderer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins

I have joined data from a csv file to my shapefile. The attribute table shows a successful join. I have converted the variable of interest to INTEGER. But when I go through Style to categorize the variable, all I get is zero. Help please!

Answer (score 2):

It's not your fault. It's a bug in QGIS 1.8. You can choose between categorizing manually or exporting the joined layer to e.g. Shapefile, and use this new file in your project.